# Debug java application in 32bit mode

Tags: 32bit-64bit, 32-bit, java, jdb

Using OpenJDK 7 from the command line on OS X Lion, how can I use `jdb` to debug an application that requires execution under a 32-bit JVM, due to JNI native code?

I know I can invoke `java` as `java -d32` and it will use a 32-bit JVM. I can also pass that `-d32` flag to `jdb` without an error, but it does not seem to have any effect: I still get the same error messages when the application tries to link its native code. Passing `-J-d32` exhibits the same behaviour.

Comment: The jdb doesn't need to be told the 32/64 bitness of the process its is debugging. I would use you IDE to do the debugging as it is much simpler. You just press the `Debug` button instead of the `Run` button.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, if jdb starts the process it is debugging, then there is noone else to tell that process its bitness. And I'm too much of a command-line person to consider an IDE a real alternative here.

Comment: Most of what you can do on the command line is just one click in an IDE. Once you get used to an IDE it will save you so much time you will wonder why you didn't do it sooner. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve the above by starting `java` and `jdb` as separate processes from two different Terminal windows. So execute these commands, each in its own window:

```
java -d32 -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=127.0.0.1:5463 -classpath . MainClass
jdb -attach 127.0.0.1:5463
```

The first will start the JVM for the application, but suspend it immediately after creation. The second will start the debugger and attach it to the JVm just created. Then you can type `run` in that second window to launch the application. As an added bonus, output from the application and the debugger are not intermixed, as each has its own window.

*References:* The [`jdb` help](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/jdb.html) lists possible command line arguments, and [JPDA](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/index.html) has a [section on transports](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html#Transports).

Although the above does work for me, I'd welcome other answers providing easier solutions, preferrably as a single command and/or without any need to choose port numbers in an arbitrary fashion. The shared memory connector does not seem to work for [my JVM](http://code.google.com/p/openjdk-osx-build/downloads/detail?name=OpenJDK-OSX-1.7-universal-u6-jdk-b24-20120813.dmg).